Galois Correspondence and Tensor-Hom Adjunction
I apologize for asking a similar question so shortly after the last one, and that my motivation is largely intuition: I am too new to both Galois theory and multilinear algebra to make this connection precise myself.
Let $N$ be a $R$-module, where $R$ is commutative. Recall that the tensor product $\_ \otimes_R N$ is left-adjoint to the Hom functor $\text{Hom}_R(N, \_)$, and of course that the latter is right adjoint to the former. Now for $N$ to be a Galois extension of $R$, $\text{Aut}_R(N)$ must act transitively on $\text{Hom}(N, \Omega)$ (normality), and $N \otimes_R \Omega$ must be a reduced $R$-algebra (separability). I cannot help but expect there to be some connection here.
The fundamental theorem itself seems to strengthen my suspicion: for instance, that quotient groups are somewhat preserved through the correspondence ($|\text{Gal}(N/R)|/|H|$ = $[N^H : R]$) seems to be an example of left-adjoint functors preserving colimits, and in general inclusion-reserving plays well with contravariance.
Could the Galois correspondence (the bijection between intermediate fields and subgroups of Galois group) be described as some variation of this adjunction, perhaps its composition with another composition which holds only when the extension is Galois? Will this allow for simplifying the proof of the fundamental theorem?
Edit: I just realized that my considerations may be related to "Hopf Galois theory," so I would certainly appreciate any pointers on that.

Please ask a concrete question.

I've tried to make my question more specific.

Ok. I think the answer is No since your adjunction is for covariant functors. But the Galois correspondence is contravariant. But maybe I misunderstood your request.
